# Rollbacking from Yaml based configuration to database based configuration

Tags: database, configuration, deployment

We recently changed the way we deploy our Drupal site on our testing environment to a docker image.

The issue is that we were using a file based configuration. The current applied configuration is not deployed with the image, only the expected configuration. So we end up with a docker container with an empty active folder and a sync folder with the latest configuration.

[image: Before-After-Deployment]

As a result, running `drush ci` crashes as it tries to create everything anew on a database on which was already applied most of the configuration.

Our strategy was to go back to a database based configuration (the default of Drupal). We tried [this](http://blog.dev030.com/posts/revert-configuration-file-based-database-based). The results were a broken website and it was impossible to run the `drush cr` anymore.

Crash when running `drush cr`:

> root@7ef127fc56af:/var/www/CMS# vendor/bin/drush cr PHP Fatal error:
> Call to undefined function system_rebuild_module_data() in
> /var/www/CMS/web/core/includes/common.inc on line 1136 PHP Stack
> trace: PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/CMS/vendor/drush/drush/drush:0 PHP
> 2. require() /var/www/CMS/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4 PHP   3. Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:66 PHP   4.
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:41 PHP   5.
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:112 PHP   6.
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148 PHP   7.
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:255 PHP   8.
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:978 PHP   9.
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255 PHP  10.
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:405
> PHP  11.
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:151
> PHP  12.
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:181
> PHP  13.
> call_user_func_array:{/var/www/CMS/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:235}()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:235
> PHP  14. Drush\Commands\core\CacheCommands->rebuild()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:235
> PHP  15. drupal_rebuild()
> /var/www/CMS/vendor/drush/drush/src/Commands/core/CacheCommands.php:203
> PHP  16. drupal_flush_all_caches()
> /var/www/CMS/web/core/includes/utility.inc:52  [error]  Drush command
> terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error. Error: Call to
> undefined function system_rebuild_module_data() in
> /var/www/CMS/web/core/includes/common.inc, line 1136

Questions:

- Did we choose the right solution by trying to fallback on a database based configuration, or is there a better idea?

We could find a way to keep the active configuration saved and put it back after each deployment, however, we use different technologies on our environments (for example we use docker for our testing environment), at first glance it seems quite complex to me.

- How can we change to a database based configuration?

Environment:

```
root@7ef127fc56af:/var/www/CMS# vendor/bin/drush status
 Drupal version : 8.7.12                                            
 Site URI       : default                                           
 DB driver      : mysql                                             
 DB hostname    : __DB_HOST__                                       
 DB port        :                                                   
 DB username    : __DB_USER__                                       
 DB name        : __DB_NAME__                                       
 PHP binary     : /usr/bin/php5.6                                   
 PHP config     : /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini                          
 PHP OS         : Linux                                             
 Drush script   : /var/www/CMS/vendor/bin/drush             
 Drush version  : 9.3.0                                             
 Drush temp     : /tmp                                              
 Drush configs  : /var/www/CMS/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml 
                  /var/www/CMS/drush/drush.yml              
 Drupal root    : /var/www/CMS/web                          
 Site path      : sites/default
```

Comment: Not sure what the difference between the actual and the expected configuration is. You just need to find a strategy to get the live config to your local dev copy and then export it once and from then on ensure that your exported config lands on live somehow and them import it there. Maybe use strategies like config ignore or config split to have different configuration in different environments. That's all. Please for your own sake don't switch back from configuration management to database configuration. You just need to find the right strategy to deploy your config.

Comment: BTW, both your PHP and your Drupal are outdated. Consider upgrading ASAP.

Comment: Can you confirm that your current strategy is this: [File system based workflow](https://www.drupal.org/docs/configuration-management/file-system-based-workflow)?

Comment: @sonfd yes this our current workflow. Sync = Staging in our case.

Comment: @leymannx So, I have my testing environment (for validation purposes) and my dev environment. When I dev locally, I then export the configuration changes I made using ```drush cex``` and commit them in ```sync```.

When I deploy, I only deploy the content of ```sync```. Since we're using a file based configuration, to import the new configuration, Drupal looks at the diff between active/sync.
Since ```active``` is not commited (as it's environment related), it's empty. So the diff is actually the full ```sync``` folder

Comment: @leymannx I looked at both `config split` and `config import` but I don't see how it could sove my problem. I already only deploy what I want to deploy, and I don't want to ignore anything.
However, when deploying, I just loose the `active` directory in the process, since it's not commited. So I could find a way to save those files and put them back on the new instances of my Drupal site, but it seemed more complicated than using a database based configuration.
But I might be mistaken.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand what the problem is. The standard is to use configuration management as explained here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/configuration-management.

Comment: @leymannx I added a schema in the post to make it clearer :) I've read the documentation you sent. I can see that they recommand to synchronize the database to deploy "If in doubt or you are not a very versed Drupal user, always synchronize the database also" [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/configuration-management/keeping-your-local-and-remote-sites-synchronized).
I don't see how it's possible without synchronizing the content as well :/